# Unity C# - Class within Array is Overriden instead of creating copy (mutiple scripts)

Tags: c#, arrays, class, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a tile mesh map in unity where each tile is a class that holds certain information. All of the tile information is held in one script called TileData. I have four tile types, each with with 4 variables. (Tile Graphic, Tile Name, Tile Pos X and Tile Pos Z.) All of the information for building the map is contained within a second script. (I am calling a local version of the tiledata script in the map script.)

I can successfully build the mesh with the tiles, by using a multidimensional array that randomly selects one tile class form an array of tile classes.
My issue is that when I try to assign position x and position z for the tile location, it overrides the information in the tile array. The end result is each tile displays the x,z of all of the other like tiles, instead of itself individually.

What I want to be able to do is build a two dimensional array of a random Class Tile, but assign each new tile their own x and z coordinate. (Which I plan to later use for movement/pathfinding etc.)

I tried every approach I could think of, even attempted a multidimensional jagged array, but couldn't get it to work.

Code (with the irrelevant bits removed) below:

**TileData Script**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class TileData {

[System.Serializable]
public class Tile                                                                   //Public class Tile to act as Tile Template.
{
    public int tileGraphic = 0;                                                     //An int to point to our Tile Graphic
    public string tileName = "Unknown";                                             //Name of the Tile.

    public int tilePositionX = 0;
    public int tilePositionZ = 0;
}

public Tile[] tileTypes = new Tile[4];                                              //Makes a new Tile Array from the Tile Class

public void makeArray()                                                             //Constructs the array.
{
    tileTypes[0] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 0, tileName = "Grassland"};            //Makes the new Tile and puts them in the array.
    tileTypes[1] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 1, tileName = "Water"};
    tileTypes[2] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 2, tileName = "Forest"};
    tileTypes[3] = new Tile { tileGraphic = 3, tileName = "Mountain"};
}
```

**Map Script**:

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    [ExecuteInEditMode]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]                                                          //Ensures the object has a filter, Renderer and Collider when created.
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]

   public class missionMap : MonoBehaviour
   {

    //Map Variables

    public int sizeX = 25;                                                                      //The left/right size of the map (in tiles). Public so it can be changed from the editor.
    public int sizeZ = 25;                                                                      //The forward/backward size of the map (in tiles).

    public float tileSize = 1.0f;                                                               //The size of each tile. (How many vertices wide the tile is.)

    //Tile Variables

    public TileData localTileData = new TileData();                                             //Pulls the tile types in from their own script.
    public TileData.Tile[,] localTileArray = new TileData.Tile[25, 25];                         //Builds an Array of our Tile class the size of our map, so each tile on the map has a Tile Class corresponding to it.    

    void Start()
    {
        localTileData.makeArray();                                                              //Calls the makeArray from the Tile Data script, so we can access the array later.

        //localTileArray[0, 0] = localTileArray[sizeX,sizeZ];

        BuildMap();                                                                             //Builds the map when the code starts.
        //BuildPathGraph();
    }
   }
```

**I omitted the actual building of the map and skip to the tiles.**

```
public void BuildTiles()
{
    for (int z = 0; z < sizeZ; z++)                                                     //A double for loop to populate our tile position array with the size of the our map in x and z.
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
        {

            localTileArray[x, z] = localTileData.tileTypes[Random.Range(0, 4)];          //Fills the Array with Tile Copies of type 0 - 3 (0 = grass, 2 = water, 3 = forest, 4 = mountain.)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in the part you omitted: building of the map. 
Are you doing something like this?

```
for (int z = 0; z < sizeZ; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
      {

        localTileArray[x, z] = localTileData;
    }
}
```

If that's the case, what you are doing is assigning a **reference** to localTileData to all the elements in the localTileArray. So that's why modifying one reference affects all elements in the array: they are all the same. This is because in C#, classes are [Reference Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

The solution is the one @graju256 talked about: use .MemberwiseClone() to create a *copy* of the localTileArray reference.

Another solution would be changing the Tile from a class to a Struct and convert it into a [Value Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) so when you assign localTileData to an element in the array, a copy is created.

Comment: .MemberwiseClone() had an error as invalid, so I looked into Structs. I was hesitant as I had never used them before. However, it works perfectly so far. I will have to spend more time with the documentation to understand the difference between Structs and Classes as they look largely interchangeable to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at the links about value/reference types I put on the answer and you'll have half of the way done in your quest for learning the difference between classes and structs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Clone the selected tile instance while building the ***localTileArray***. So that, you can avoid modifying / referencing the same instance in your program.

You may reconsider your TILE design. Declare enum for your TILE type and pass it at creation time. Create new TILE with it's type while building your internal array. So that, you can avoid maintaining TILE type instances.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you give a code example? If I make a new TILE, it will not be one of the four types, it will just be a basic TILE.

Comment: Use MemberwiseClone method to clone your TILE object. 

`localTileArray[x, z] = localTileData.tileTypes[Random.Range(0, 4)].MemberwiseClone();`

As the TILE class is composed of value types, it's OK to clone the object by shallow-copy. Otherwise, we should consider the deep-copy by implementing ICloneable interface.